# CSV manipulation using php

Tags: php, file, csv

Hey everyone I am learning some php and manipulating some csv files here. I'm creating a random key generator for some courses. Basically I am adding a new column with the keys for a course.

I have managed to do this. However when I run my script I get an extra row being read and a key generated for that. Example if I have 3 courses A,B,C then 4 keys would be generated and added to the csv.

Can I have some help or tips on reading and writing to a csv?

```
<?php
$file= fopen("input.csv","r");
$output=fopen("output.csv","w");
function gen_keys($length=10)
{
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

//echo gen_keys();
$list=array();
while(!feof($file))
{

    //print_r(fgetcsv($file));
    $list=fgetcsv($file);
    //$list=array_filter($list);
    $list[]=gen_keys();
    echo "<br />";
    print_r($list);
    fputcsv($output, $list);
    //print_r(fgetcsv($output));

}
fclose($file);
fclose($output);?>
```

Input :
comp1400

comp2000

info2425

eng1234

Comment: What is the content of `input.csv` ?

Comment: row1: comp1400
row2: comp2000
row3: info2425
row4: eng1234

no other data. i wanted to just get the generated keys in the column next to the course eg
comp1400 , 123ABC 
and so forth

Answer (score 1):

Here is updated and working version:

```
$list=fgetcsv($file);
if (!empty($list)) {
    //$list=array_filter($list);
    $list[]=gen_keys();
    echo "<br />";
    print_r($list);
    fputcsv($output, $list);
}
```

Please note line with `if (!empty($list)) {` it checks if we have any imput.

More information about `empty()` in [documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Comment: Thanks alot that did some my problem!. Can you tell me where i where i went wrong from before?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$infp = fopen("in.csv", "r");
$outfp = fopen("out.csv", "w");

while(!feof($infp)) {
  $list = fgetcsv($infp);
  // change $list and write to output
  fputcsv($outfp, $list);
}
```